# WinMinimize PID after MsgBox

Tags: autohotkey

The following code opens notepad, then [minimizes](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) it. It works fine:

```
!^m::
Run, Notepad.exe,,USEERRORLEVEL MAX, PID
WinWait, ahk_pid %pid%
WinMinimize, ahk_pid %PID%
return
```

However if I add an `MsgBox` to display the PID before minimizing the notepad window, then the latter doesn't get minimized:

```
!^m::
Run, Notepad.exe,,USEERRORLEVEL MAX, PID
WinWait, ahk_pid %pid%
MsgBox OK %PID%
WinMinimize, ahk_pid %PID%
return
```

Why?

Sleeping didn't help:

```
!^m::
Run, Notepad.exe,,USEERRORLEVEL MAX, PID
WinWait, ahk_pid %pid%
MsgBox OK %PID%
Sleep, 2000  ; 2 seconds
WinMinimize, ahk_pid %PID%
return
```

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and AHK 1.1.13.01 (October 11, 2013). I have the same issue with Version v1.0.48.05 and Version v1.1.15.02. All AHK versions I tried are 32-bit.

---

Edit:

`!^b::WinMinimize, ahk_pid 9156` doesn't even work. (9156 being a valid PID)

Following MCL suggestion, I also unsuccessfully tried:

```
!^t::
PID = 11692
hwnd := WinExist("ahk_pid " pid)
WinMinimize, ahk_id %hwnd%
return
```

Comment: For me your script works with Win7 SP1 x64 Professional and AHK 32bit v1.1.15.00

Comment: I'm running AHK in WinXP SP3 compatibility mode and with elevated rights

Comment: @hippibruder Thanks, I upgraded my AHK to the newest version, I still have the same issue. Does `!^b::WinMinimize, ahk_pid 9156` work for you? (replacing the 9156 by some existing PID) On my computer, it doesn't.

Comment: What about retrieving the window's hwnd first? `hwnd := WinExist("ahk_pid " pid)` then `WinMinimize, ahk_id %hwnd%`

Comment: @MCL Thanks, good idea, but didn't work :/

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (it is tested and is working):

```
!^m::
Run, Notepad.exe,,MAX, PID
CheckWin:
IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad
{
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
    MsgBox OK %PID%
    WinMinimize, Untitled - Notepad
}
else
{
    Goto, CheckWin
}
return
```

`WinWait` and `WinMinimize` commands cannot use Process ID (PID). In my code I am using WinTitle with these commands.

I am using `IfWinExist` command to be sure that notepad.exe is already launched and only after use `WinWait` and `WinMinimize` commands.